# Try /Exception in Function Python

Tags: python

just started playing with python came across a little problem
simple example area of square with exception handling for wrong input
works when integers are correctly input --but should I input and string or char-I get Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex3.py", line 29, in 
    area = width * length
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def error():
        print "no parameter entered - please enter parameter"

def get_width():
        width = None
        try:
                width = int(raw_input("please enter width of the room in meters: "))
                return width
        except:
                error()
                get_width()

def get_length():
        length = None
        try:
                length = int(raw_input("please enter length of the room in meters: "))
                return length

        except:
                error()
                get_length()

print "\nExercise 3: Area of a Room"

width = get_width()
length = get_length()
area = width * length

print "The area of a room with a width of "+str(width)+" and a length of "+str(length)+" is "+str(area)+" squared meters\n"
```

any help/explanation would be great thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make a recursive call, but the result isn't going anywhere. You need to return it. For example:

```
return get_width()
```

Comment: AH! ..awesome thankyou! - it works , but only half understand, i use the function recursively yes, woudnt the return width handle the result of this call too?